# MATLAB to C codegen build error - input properties specification mismatch

Tags: c, matlab, code-generation, matlab-coder, codegen

I am trying to build a `C/C++` static library from `MATLAB` code, but receive the following error:

> "Function 'application' input properties specification mismatch:
>   expected 0 but found 2."

Here is the function that I am trying to convert:

```
function [  ] = application( )
%#codegen

global a
global b
global c
global d
global e

[e, d] = calculate(a, b, c, d);

end
```

As you can see there are no local inputs or outputs defined in the function. Before building, I have defined all my global variable types, as well as set their initial values. When testing my code in MATLAB, I fill global variables a, b, c and d with data before running "`application.m`" from a main `MATLAB` script.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. These are different languages!

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, I realise they are different - the output type from the MATLAB window itself for a static library is actually phrased "C/C++ Static Library" (please see [link](http://i.imgur.com/CAj28kG.png) to screenshot image).  Any other help would be awesome!

Comment: Did you specify inputs for "application" some how? It could be either input properties or a test function calling this function. There should not be any inputs based on the code you have shown.